# jQuery code not working from internal stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a small script made by me in Wordpress. While entering it in Google Chrome console everything seems fine, the code is working, but when I call it via `<script src="filepath.js">` it doesn't work at all.

I already tried to insert the script using `wp_enqueue_script`, but I'm not good at PHP. The script and the code are the following:

```
if ($('body.single-product').length || $('body.product-template-default').length) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.trx-stretch-width-wrap').prepend('<section class="vc_cta3-container alert-acquisto"><div class="vc_general vc_cta3 vc_cta3-style-classic vc_cta3-shape-rounded vc_cta3-align-left vc_cta3-color-classic vc_cta3-icon-size-md"><div class="vc_cta3_content-container"><div class="vc_cta3-content"><p>Per acquistare i prodotti, contattare attraverso la pagina <a href="/contatti/">Contatti</a> o telefonare lo <a href="tel:+33333333">333333333</a></p></div></div></div></section>');
  })
};
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/child-theme/prova.js'></script>
```

Between the `||` there are the classes of the pages I want it to display, then with jQuery I'm trying to put it before the `trx-stretch-etc` class.

Actually, analyzing the waterfall it calls the script, but it seems that the script does nothing at all, don't know if I wrote something wrong, any syntax error, or somewhat. Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: have you tried a simple console.log to see if it's called properly?

Comment: It says  **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if**
It's like he's not reading the code properly

Comment: Try adding an else statement in your code and see if that gets executed?

Comment: your if statement should be inside the document.ready - not the other way round :)

Comment: @treyBake It keep not working, I made the code simpler, can you tell me if something isn't ok? 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                        $('.trx-stretch-width-wrap').prepend('<htmlcode>');    
});

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tpf58mxy/

Comment: nothing wrong with your code - maybe something wrong in include order of .js files - or the elements don't exist on the page

Comment: @treyBake if it can help, I'd give you the link so you can check that inclusion and all is ok, even in the console.log works. (https://www.vinipetrosino.it/wine/sciascinoso-igt/)

Comment: @Antoyosh I see no console log or console errors

Comment: @treyBake I think I'll give up, don't know what else to do to make it work haha